# How to cast an instance of these similar classes?

Tags: c#, casting

I have two Classes that derive from a mutual class A, which contains some properties (mainly stings and integers). Class B is a different class containing additional properties. More precisely,

```
public class A1 : A {
    private B _bee;
    public B Bee {
        get { return _bee;}
        set { _bee = value;}
    }
}

public class A2 : A {
    private List<B> _beeList;
    public List<B> BeeList {
        get { return _beeList;}
        set { _beeList = value;}
    }
}
```

Now, given an instance of A1, how can I make an instance of A2 containing the same information (i.e., the properties in the 'A' part, and the instance of 'B'). I tried the following - I wished it'd work, but knew it wouldn't... - (Let me call my instance of A1 resp. A2 by 'one' resp. 'two'):

```
A _a = (A)one; // This obv works
B _b = one.Bee; 

A2 _a2 = (A2)_a; // Threw away the Bee - information, so should work imo
_a2.BeeList.Add(_b);
```

So how do I do this without populating all properties in A by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 using System.Reflection;  

  private void Convert(A1 _a1, A2 _a2)
    {
        foreach(PropertyInfo pi in typeof(A).GetProperties())
        {
            pi.SetValue(_a2,
                pi.GetValue(_a1, null)
                            , null);
        }
        _a2.BeeList.Add(_a1.Bee);
    }
```

this seemed to work for me

Comment: No problem, if you look into the `GetValue` and `SetValue` methods, you may find some flags that can replace the nulls to help you further if needed

Answer (score 2):

try using [automapper](http://automapper.org/).

automapper enables you to copy properties of a class to another class without writing much code.

ex:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<X, Y>();    
Y y = Mapper.Map<X, Y>(x);
```

Comment: There should be a short, non-3rd-party way of doing this in C#... Se my comment to ryadavillis answer. But I will check out AutoMapper later, although I am not a fan of using external stuff.

Answer (score 1):

[Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) configuration would look like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A1, A2>()
      .ForMember(a2 => a2.BeeList, ctx => ctx.MapFrom(a1 => new List<B>{a1.Bee}));

A a1Object = new A1{Bee = new B()};

A2 a2Object = Mapper.Map<A2>(a1Object);
```